# Do I need a transit visa at Dubai International Airport (DXB) for an international connection

Tags: transit, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, dubai, dxb

I am a Pakistani national and need to transit through Dubai International Airport (DXB).

I am not planning to leave the airport and both of my flights (arrival and departure) are from Terminal 3.

I am pretty sure that I do not need transit visa at the DXB, however it is no where mentioned on any of their official website.

Can anyone please provide me such a link stating that transiting without leaving the airport does not require visa at DXB, as I need to use this link as a proof for a visa application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, You do not need a visa for an airside transit at Dubai. Just for the record, even if you had different terminals on DXB you would still not need a visa.

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Source: [Timatic via Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&DC=GB&DV=United%20Kingdom&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=77db2a5e2a6d9e7c2c076e154b6f6d54fe3c8)

However, if you have a transit time of more than 8 hours you can also obtain a Transit visa on arrival and go enjoy.

> Visa Issuance:
>
> E-transit visas can be obtained before departure. Passengers must have a printed e-transit visa confirmation and they can transit for a maximum stay of 48 hours.
>
> The passengers must transit for at least 8 hours.
>
> Passengers can obtain a transit visa at Abu Dhabi (AUH), Dubai (DXB), Ras al Khaimah (RKT) or Sharjah (SHJ) for a maximum of 96 hours. The passenger must:
>
> - transit for at least 8 hours; and
> - have onward ticket to a third country; and
> - have a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
>
> Visas are only issued as a part of a transit package together with hotel accommodation and airport transfer.

Source: [Timatic via Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&DC=GB&DV=United%20Kingdom&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=77db2a5e2a6d9e7c2c076e154b6f6d54fe3c8)